# clojure template variadic macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I tried the following code (learning about macros):

```
(require '[clojure.template :as temp])

(defn fna [x] (println "a" x) x)
(defn fnb [x] (println "b" x) x)

(temp/apply-template '[& fns]
                     '(fn [payload] (-> payload fns))
                     '[fna fnb])
;; returns (fn [payload] (-> payload fnb))
```

I am surprised by the output, as I was expecting:

```
(fn [payload] (-> payload fna fnb))
```

Why is it producing this output, and what would be a way to achieve the above? I specifically says in the doc:

> argv is an argument list, as in defn.

Note: it could be written like so, but I am trying to understand how to use template:

```
(defmacro wrap-fn-> [& fns]
  `(fn [~'x#]
     (-> ~'x
         ~@fns)))
```

Comment: I would say, if you are learning to use `template` because you hope it will be useful, don't bother. It is not used in real life outside of clojure.test, and it is a fairly limited tool; knowing how to write the macro yourself will serve you far better.

Answer (score 1):

The examples here

- https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.template-api.html
- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.template/apply-template

do not show the use of "rest args" like `[& fns]`.  I think that is where you are going wrong.  Try this:

```
(println
  (temp/apply-template
    '[x y]
    '(fn [payload] (-> payload x y))
    '[fna fnb]))

=> (fn [payload] (-> payload fna fnb))
```

BTW, I've never seen `clojure.template` in use before - it looks like a very specialized tool.

Comment: Yes it would work like that, but for a fixed number of `fns`, I am trying to make it take a variadic number of arguments.
Note, this is for learning purposes (never saw it before looking in the clojure.test source). And in practice I would use the `defmacro` to take a variable number of arguments, and pass it to `apply-template` anyway. This is pure curiosity (so far). Moreover I don't see why it would take `fnb` rather than `fna`.

Comment: It "takes" `fnb` because `[& fns]` is an argument list containing two symbols, `&` and `fns`. Your template definition ignores the first argument, named `&` and passed `fna`, and uses only the second argument, named `fns` and passed `fnb`.